# ActiveRecord update from hash directly without getting each attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

This is one user record.

```
{"id"=>1, "name"=>"jack", "age"=>43, "job"=>"driver"}
```

I want to update this user using the below data.

```
@user = {"id"=>1, "name"=>"tomas", "age"=>35, "job"=>"developer"}
```

I can update this user in this way.

```
name, age, job = @user.values_at(:name, :age, :job)
User.update(1, :name => name, :age => age, :job => job)
```

But I want to know if it is possible to update using the `@user` directly without getting each attribute like when we create the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you like this better?

```
User.update(@user[:id], @user.slice(:name, :age, :job))
```

And when you are on Ruby on Rails 6.0 *and* you are using a PostgreSQL database that you can use `upsert` like this:

```
User.upsert(@user, unique_by: :id)
```

Comment: I am on Rails 5 but I am getting this issue.
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

Comment: Updated to Rails 6 and upsert helped me. Thank you!